# svglite, svgPanZoom not able to plot in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, svgpanzoom, svglite

According to the post [How to display scatter plot with R Packages:svgPanZoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055111/how-to-display-scatter-plot-with-r-packagessvgpanzoom) I tried to replicate a zoomable plot in R shiny. Can someone help me with my code? Why can't I reproduce this code?

```
library(shiny)
library(svglite)
library(svgPanZoom)


# Define UI ----
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    # App title ----
  headerPanel("Cyl vtree"),
  
    
 # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  svgPanZoom(
    svglite:::inlineSVG(
      show(p)
    ),
    controlIconsEnabled = T
  )
  
))

# Define server logic to plot ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$main_plot <- renderSvgPanZoom({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
    svgPanZoom(p, controlIconsEnabled = T)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `svgPanZoomOutput` is missing in your UI to bind svgpanzoom to shiny
2. You have used `svgPanZoom` in UI which only belongs to `renderSvgPanZoom` in server
3. It works in either way - using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056085/9220442) or just the basic example from `?svgPanZoom`

```r
library(shiny)
library(svglite)
library(svgPanZoom)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridSVG)

# Define UI ----
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Cyl vtree"),
  
  
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  svgPanZoomOutput(outputId = "main_plot")
  
  
))

# Define server logic to plot ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$main_plot <- renderSvgPanZoom({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

    svgPanZoom(p, controlIconsEnabled = T)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. After trying your solution I ran again in an error message: "for best results with ggplot2 and lattice, please install gridSVG
Warnung: Error in : '' does not exist in current working directory ('F:/R_Project/...)". Then I installed gridSVG and put library(gridSVG) and things worked. Thank you again. Step by step I am getting into it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, changed my answer accordingly